# How to differentiate code chage commits to publishing commits in jekyll git repo?

Tags: jekyll

If I have a Jekyll website and constantly publish articles do I need to commit the changes to the main repository every time I have a new article? I feel like that will be like spam the git blog publishing commit logs and actual important code changes will be buried in the commit log. Also, do I need to commit and describe changes every time I have a new article? How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You should think the process of publishing a post in a static generator as publishing code, there is no difference for git logs, each post becomes part of your website and it is needed for the proper website to render your full website in any git repo.